# How to remove backstack pages to exit application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, exit

I have an application which displays a disclaimer page when it is first run. Once you select Accept or Deny you never see the page again.

However, when you press the back key attempting to close the application after the first run, you go back to the disclaimer page, then if you hit it again, back to the main page and then again to exit.

This only happens the first time the application is run, but I would like to have the application ignore the disclaimer page when the back key is pressed and exit the application.

Other than forcing an unhandled exception error to close the app, are there any other options?

Thanks in advance.

Solution: Add the below `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` in my main page.

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do it, but I was in a hurry, so I implemented it in a following way.

I have a static global enum that stores the last page I was on.  Assuming you have pages called `pgDisclaimer` and `pgMain`.

In the `OnNavigatedTo` event of the `pgDisclaimer` page, check to see where the control came from.  If it came from `pgMain`, just execute `NavigationService.GoBack()` and you'll be out of the application and the user will never actually see `pgDisclaimer` page (not even a flicker).

Edit: Found the more elegant way.  In Mango, you can use the horribly named `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` method.

Comment: Thats one way to do it. THanks for the suggestion, but I think a popup would be the best solution if I can work that.

Comment: @Rhys See my edit - MS has addressed this very problem in Mango.

Comment: Thanks.. I used the below in my main page. and it works..         `private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }`

Answer (score 3):

You should display the Disclaimer as a popup rather than a page, that way you don't have to worry about navigation and backstack issues.  I saw this mentioned in a Channel 9 video:

[Windows Phone: building apps that customers love, end to end](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-935T)

The specific part in the presentation that covers this is at around 26:20.  He's discussing a login page that prevents a user from navigating back out of the app, but the concept is similar.

Also, from this [MSDN Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx):

> I forgot the #1 piece of advice regarding EULA / Login screens - don't make them into pages. If you instead make them Popup controls you can show or hide them at any time (on first navigation; when the user hits a "protected" part of the app; after a time-out; etc.) and they don't consume a slot in the backstack. This should cover the majority of cases.

Comment: If you can find that link, that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I went for the `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` solution